# Check if the sibling of an element has a child that is a checkbox in jquery

Tags: jquery

**HTML Code:**

```
<div>
    <div>
        <input id="chkA" type="checkbox" name="chkA">           
    </div>                                                  
    <div>A</div>
    <div id="A"></div>
</div>
```

**Context is:**

```
<div id="A"></div>
```

**Problem:**

I want to navigate to the first sibling of `<div id="A"></div>` and check if it has a child of type input/checkbox.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 if( $("#A").siblings().first().children("input[type='checkbox']").length > 0) {
    //code
 }
```

Comment: if($("#A").siblings().first().children("input[type='checkbox']").length is returning 0. It should however return 1.

Comment: It works here.  I copied your provided markup and my javascript: http://jsfiddle.net/Uv9Js/

Comment: oops..! Sorry, yes it works. I was referencing a class "A" instead of an ID "A" in $("#A"). Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try this

If you know the sibling is below the element

```
if($("#A").next().chldren(":checkbox").length){
     //Yes I am a checkbox
}
```

Or if it is above

```
if($("#A").prev().chldren(":checkbox").length){
     //Yes I am a checkbox
}
```

Or if you dont know

```
if($("#A").siblings(":first").chldren(":checkbox").length){
     //Yes I am a checkbox
}
```

Comment: ($("#A").siblings(":first").chldren(":checkbox").length) is returning 0. It should however return 1.

Answer (score 0):

```
if($('#A').prevAll().has(':checkbox').length>0) {
//code
}
```

Comment: I think `.prevAll()` should be used instead of `.prev()`

Comment: You are right actually I missed one of the divs. Fixed now